# How to find start and end dates of monitoring locations

Tags: r, data.table

I have meteorological datasets from NCDC, with 30 to 70 years of hourly observations for each station. Each record includes the ID, latitude, longitude and elevation of the weather station. A station (site) can move several times over 70 years, without changing station name or ID. I want to make a "station history" list of the different locations, indicated by changes in latitude, longitude and/or elevation (lat, lon, elev). I had R code that worked, until I found a station that after several moves returned to an old location. That broke my R code.

The data for one station has about 770000 rows and 35 columns. I am using data.table.

Simplified example dataset with two stations "A" and "B":

```r
require("data.table")   # ver 1.9.5
DT=data.table(site=c(rep("A",8),rep("B",4)),
                 date=c(seq(from=as.POSIXct("2014-03-01",tz="GMT"), by="day", length.out=8),
                            seq(from=as.POSIXct("2014-07-01",tz="GMT"), by="day", length.out=4)),
                 lat=c(rep(30.1,3),rep(30.2,3),rep(30.1,2),rep(40.3,2),rep(40.4,2)),
                 lon=rep(50.7,12),
                 elev=c(35.0,35,36,36,35,35,35,35,51,52,52,52),
                 x=as.numeric(1:12))   # x is some meteorological data
setkey(DT,site,date)
DT
#    site                date  lat  lon elev  x
#  1:    A 2014-03-01 01:00:00 30.1 50.7   35  1
#  2:    A 2014-03-02 01:00:00 30.1 50.7   35  2
#  3:    A 2014-03-03 01:00:00 30.1 50.7   36  3
#  4:    A 2014-03-04 01:00:00 30.2 50.7   36  4
#  5:    A 2014-03-05 01:00:00 30.2 50.7   35  5
#  6:    A 2014-03-06 01:00:00 30.2 50.7   35  6
#  7:    A 2014-03-07 01:00:00 30.1 50.7   35  7
#  8:    A 2014-03-08 01:00:00 30.1 50.7   35  8
#  9:    B 2014-07-01 02:00:00 40.3 50.7   51  9
# 10:    B 2014-07-02 02:00:00 40.3 50.7   52 10
# 11:    B 2014-07-03 02:00:00 40.4 50.7   52 11
# 12:    B 2014-07-04 02:00:00 40.4 50.7   52 12
```

The list of unique locations for each station is:

```r
DT.loc <- unique(DT[,.(site,lat,lon,elev)])
DT.loc
#    site  lat  lon elev
# 1:    A 30.1 50.7   35
# 2:    A 30.1 50.7   36
# 3:    A 30.2 50.7   36
# 4:    A 30.2 50.7   35
# 5:    B 40.3 50.7   51
# 6:    B 40.3 50.7   52
# 7:    B 40.4 50.7   52
```

This would be most of what I need, but note in DT row 7-8 that station "A" returns to the first location.

The desired output is a list of the locations, with the first and last dates for each period of observations at a location.

```r
#    site          date.first           date.last  lat  lon elev
# 1:    A 2014-03-01 01:00:00 2014-03-02 01:00:00 30.1 50.7   35
# 2:    A 2014-03-03 01:00:00 2014-03-03 01:00:00 30.1 50.7   36
# 3:    A 2014-03-04 01:00:00 2014-03-04 01:00:00 30.2 50.7   36
# 4:    A 2014-03-05 01:00:00 2014-03-06 01:00:00 30.2 50.7   35
# 5:    A 2014-03-07 01:00:00 2014-03-08 01:00:00 30.1 50.7   35
# 6:    B 2014-07-01 02:00:00 2014-07-01 02:00:00 40.3 50.7   51
# 7:    B 2014-07-02 02:00:00 2014-07-02 02:00:00 40.3 50.7   52
# 8:    B 2014-07-03 02:00:00 2014-07-04 02:00:00 40.4 50.7   52
```

I originally had the following code to produce a similar list, but it didn't identify the return to an old location.

```r
# find first occurence of each location. 
# This requires DT to be keyed on site,lat,lon,elev,date
setkey(DT,site,lat,lon,elev,date)
DT.loc.first <- DT[DT.loc, mult="first", which=TRUE]
# find last occurence of each location
DT.loc.last <- DT[DT.loc, mult="last", which=TRUE]
# get first rows and select columns for history table
DT.hist <- DT[DT.loc.first, .(site,date.first=date,lat,lon,elev)]
# add date from last row for location
DT.hist[, date.last:=DT[DT.loc.last,date]]
# rearrange and sort the history table
DT.hist <- DT.hist[,.(site,date.first,date.last,lat,lon,elev)]
setkey(DT.hist,site,date.first)
DT.hist
#    site          date.first           date.last  lat  lon elev
# 1:    A 2014-03-01 01:00:00 2014-03-08 01:00:00 30.1 50.7   35
# 2:    A 2014-03-03 01:00:00 2014-03-03 01:00:00 30.1 50.7   36
# 3:    A 2014-03-04 01:00:00 2014-03-04 01:00:00 30.2 50.7   36
# 4:    A 2014-03-05 01:00:00 2014-03-06 01:00:00 30.2 50.7   35
# 5:    B 2014-07-01 02:00:00 2014-07-01 02:00:00 40.3 50.7   51
# 6:    B 2014-07-02 02:00:00 2014-07-02 02:00:00 40.3 50.7   52
# 7:    B 2014-07-03 02:00:00 2014-07-04 02:00:00 40.4 50.7   52
```

The date.last for the first location is actually the date.last for the second occupation of the first location, and should have a separate line (after line 4 above), since station "A" actually has 5 periods of observation.

How can I create the desired station history, with first and last dates at each contiguous period at a location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elegant answer by Arun in comment to Khashaa answer:

```
# making use of DT's sort order on site,date:
DT.hist <- DT[, .(date.first=date[1L], date.last=date[.N]),
              by=.(rleid(site,lat,lon,elev),site,lat,lon,elev)]

# select columns and set sort key of result
DT.hist <- DT.hist[,.(date.last,lat,lon,elev),keyby=.(site,date.first)]
DT.hist
#    site          date.first           date.last  lat  lon elev
# 1:    A 2014-03-01 01:00:00 2014-03-02 01:00:00 30.1 50.7   35
# 2:    A 2014-03-03 01:00:00 2014-03-03 01:00:00 30.1 50.7   36
# 3:    A 2014-03-04 01:00:00 2014-03-04 01:00:00 30.2 50.7   36
# 4:    A 2014-03-05 01:00:00 2014-03-06 01:00:00 30.2 50.7   35
# 5:    A 2014-03-07 01:00:00 2014-03-08 01:00:00 30.1 50.7   35
# 6:    B 2014-07-01 02:00:00 2014-07-01 02:00:00 40.3 50.7   51
# 7:    B 2014-07-02 02:00:00 2014-07-02 02:00:00 40.3 50.7   52
# 8:    B 2014-07-03 02:00:00 2014-07-04 02:00:00 40.4 50.7   52
```

This creates the history table without modifying DT or changing DT's key.
Adding site,lat,lon,elev to the by= cleanly adds these columns to the output, even though they don't change the grouping (redundant to rleid).

Alternatively, without site,lat,lon,elev in the by= :

```
DT.hist2 <- DT[, .(date.first=date[1L], date.last=date[.N],
               lat=lat[1L], lon=lon[1L], elev=elev[1L]), 
               by=.(rleid(site,lat,lon,elev))]
```

but this is more to type, and not easier to read.